# Backend 3D Model of Three.js / Where is the Tree?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I had a look at a few showcases of WebGL lately and found three.js which seems to be a very popular framework (so popular that oreillys book on webgl by Toni Parsli seems to focus on Three.js extensively).

Now I had a look at the source of three.js, and was wondering, why I could not find some kind of a scene tree in the sources to hold the objects. I had expected to find something like a BSP, a k-d-tree or an octree somewhere in the sources.

What I found was the "Flattened List", which seems to hold the objects: http://ushiroad.com/3j/

No I am a bit flubbergusted. Why would  one keep the scene in a flat datastructure? I would assume that a tree would be the better solution.

Have I missed a tree structure in the source (needless to say that I did not read it line by line) or is there something about Scene graph optimization that I have not understood?

PS: I was also thinking whether the Flattened List is an intermediate object after pruning of the scene graph. Yet I could not find indication for that in the source, although http://ushiroad.com/3j/ seems to indicate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A back-end tree structure was not added because it was not needed.

If you need a tree structure at the application layer, then have a look at https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree and https://gist.github.com/chandlerprall/1484619.

Comment: Does this imply the need for a server-side octree?

Comment: Yes, kind of ;) I would say, that I still do not quite grok, why such a datastructure is not being used, are tree traversals so expensive in javascript?

Comment: No. The reason they are not being used in the back-end is because they are not needed.

Comment: Why did you unaccept this answer? There is no tree, and I answered your question.

Comment: You have answered to a fundamental part of my question thats right. Yet I still do not know *why* a tree or graph like structure is not used. You only wrote that it is not needed, now I just thought other people were more likely to look at the question again if it were marked unanswered. I appreciate your answer (upvote) yet one piece of my question remains unanswered. Why is there no tree structure to cut down asymptotic complexity?

Comment: I have given you the best answer I can. If you identify a specific place in the code where a tree benefits performance, you can code it up and submit a pull request. All help is welcome.